# New row with ComboBox in DataGridView (WinForms)

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I'm using DataGridView with ComboBox. When I start with a new row in my DataGridView I create a new Guid with Guid.NewGuid() in DefaultValuesNeeded event. This works well, but when I move to the next (new) row I get the following error message: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Relative code

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
CombBox cb = (ComboBox)sender; 
string item = cb.SelectedValue.ToString(); 
dt = ta.GetData(item); 
dgvMain.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value = dt.Rows[0]["text"].ToString();
```

Update:

For best of my understanding "SelectedIndexChanged" fires earlier than I need, on new row creation. On this stage the DataTable is not populated yet, that's why it raises an exception. Pls correct me if I'm wrong. I fixed my code and it runs now...

```
private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            lp.ITDataSetTableAdapters.lp002_TableAdapter ta = new ITDataSetTableAdapters.lp002_TableAdapter();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string item = "";
            ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)sender;
            if (cb.SelectedValue != null)
            {
                item = cb.SelectedValue.ToString();
                dt = ta.GetData(item);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    dgvMain.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value = dt.Rows[0]["text"].ToString();
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Without code that shows what are you doing it is really a guess try to answer to this question

Comment: Sorry, here is the code: DataTable dt = new DataTable();
CombBox cb = (ComboBox)sender;
string item = cb.SelectedValue.ToString();

dt = ta.GetData(item);
dgvMain.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value = dt.Rows[0]["text"].ToString();

Comment: I have moved your code inside your question. Comments are not the best place to write multiline code.

Comment: SelectedValue could be null, dt is reassigned from the call to GetData and thus could also be null. You should use the debugger and check what of these variables is null and (using them) raises the exception